# Is it possible to commit a log file of commits quickly?

Tags: git

In my repository 'A', I fetched from a remote repository 'B'. Now I want to commit a long list of specific commits from B that I have stored in a log file onto A. Can anyone think of a way to do this besides manually cherry-picking each commit. I understand this is a very obscure situation and is not what Git is designed for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a script that iterates over your list of comments and do `git cherry-pick $i` for each entry.

For example, if file `commits.txt` is like this:

```
223373387c94dbd16ea357cebc95d616031e96a1
9b04028e3c378b6b60f8e950d43217b764edef35
ac28f924148c0597aaeaa0cf7f5cbbf54a9eec0f
```

you can do this:

```
for i in `cat commits.txt`; do git cherry-pick $i || break; done
```

Comment: While it is probably [safe to use backticks](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks) in this scenario, the standard idiom is `while read i; do ... done <commits.txt`.

Comment: @Vi. I was thinking of doing something along these lines but am not such how such a script would deal with conflicts if they occurred (and I am expecting them to). What do you think?

Comment: It will abort on the first failed cherry-pick. This is what `|| break` for. You can manually resolve the conflict, edit already applied cherry-picks away from `commits.txt` and rerun the script.